# Remove a var from a Queue Using Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to write a function that gets a Queue and parameter (int), the function deletes the var in the Queue that equals to the parameter. Here is my code:

```
public static void remove_it( Queue <Integer> q, int x)
{

    Queue <Integer> temp = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    boolean found = false;
    if (!q.isEmpty())
    {
        if (q.peek()==x)
            found = true;
        temp.add(q.remove());
    }

    boolean b;
    if (found)
    {
        b = true;

        while (!temp.isEmpty())
        {
            if (temp.peek() == x  && b)
            {
                temp.remove();
                b = false;
            }
            else
                q.add(temp.remove());
        }
    }

}
```

However, it deletes the first var of the Queue anytime... why is that?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: You need to clean up your brackets. This line: `temp.add(q.remove());` executes every time because it's outside the scope of the preceding `if` statement.

Comment: You can do the whole task in one line: `q.remove(new Integer(x));`

Answer (score 5):

To fix your bug, replace it all with one line:

```
public static void remove_it(Queue <Integer> q, int x) {
    q.remove(x);
}
```

Comment: You don't need need to explicitly create the `Integer` instance, do you? `q.remove(x)` should do...

Comment: @ErnestKiwele see recent comment added to my answer.

Comment: Not on `Queue`. Queue has `.remove()` and `.remove(Object)`, doesn't have an index-based `remove` like `List`.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I don't know why, but I was thinking `List`... you are quite right. It's even simpler now.